# Switch user role on subscription expiration in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, subscription, user-roles

In Woocommerce, I am using [YITH WooCommerce Subscription](https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-subscription/) plugin and I want to change user role when a subscription get expired.

For that I know that I have to use this hook:

```
add_action( 'subscription_expired', 'my_function', 10, 2 );

function my_function( $user_id, $subscription_key ) {
    $sub= wcs_get_subscription_from_key( $subscription_key );
    // do something
}
```

Now I have two base roles, `agencia` and `talento`, how can I make it so when a subscription expires, it changes the user role from `agencia_pro` or `agencia_pro_plus` back to `agencia` and `talento_pro` or `talento_pro_plus` to `talento`?

How can I make a function that checks the user roles and change it to either `talento` or `agencia` based on its current user role?

Thanks.

Comment: This can get pretty complex, I've only changed user capabilities programmatically before but I know you'll need to tap into the WP_User class. Check this out for an overview: https://usersinsights.com/wordpress-custom-role/

Answer (score 1):

YITH Woocommerce subscription free plugin seems to be closed **and don't allow customizations**…

For Official [Woocommerce Subscriptions plugin](https://docs.woocommerce.com/documentation/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce-extensions/woocommerce-subscriptions/) use the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_subscription_status_expired', 'change_user_role_on_subscription_expired', 10, 1 );
function change_user_role_on_subscription_expired( $subscription ) {
    // Get WP_User Object from subscription
    $user = new WP_User($subscription->get_user_id());

    if ( in_array('agencia_pro', $user->roles) ) {
        $user->remove_role( 'agencia_pro' );
        $user->add_role( 'agencia' );
    }
    elseif ( in_array('agencia_pro_plus', $user->roles) ) {
        $user->remove_role( 'agencia_pro_plus' );
        $user->add_role( 'agencia' );
    }
    elseif ( in_array('talento_pro', $user->roles) ) {
        $user->remove_role( 'talento_pro' );
        $user->add_role( 'talento' );
    }
    elseif ( in_array('talento_pro_plus', $user->roles) ) {
        $user->remove_role( 'talento_pro_plus' );
        $user->add_role( 'talento' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested, it should works.

Comment: Thank you, yes I'm using this plugin https://pt.wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-subscription/ I'm gonna give it a try

Comment: Is there any problem in using `add_action( 'subscription_expired'` instead of `add_action( 'woocommerce_subscription_status_expired'` ?

Comment: Do you know any wordpress plugin that lets you know all the available hooks on your site? or so that I can see the available hooks of any plugin?

Comment: @SteveKess I have visited the source code of the free plugin, and there is no action hook available for that… So it seems not possible for YITH Woocommerce subscription free plugin to change user role using hooks… Now Official commercial Woocommerce Subscriptions plugin allows that.

Comment: Do you know if the official Woocommerce subscription plugin is free?